# How do I tell what transactions or SQL queries or service calls are captured in the scope of a TransactionScope in debug?

Tags: c#, wcf, ado.net, transactionscope

How do I tell what transactions or SQL queries or service calls are captured in the scope of a `TransactionScope` in debug?

Surely if they are within a `TransactionScope`, there would be a way to confirm what is under its umbrella?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction scope is started once you create a new TransactionScope object,it determines which transaction to participate in.Once determined, the scope always participates in that transaction. The decision is based on two factors: whether an ambient transaction is present and the value of the TransactionScopeOption parameter in the constructor.

You can check out the link below for more details : [Implementing an Implicit Transaction using Transaction Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms172152(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: I am creating a service agent then firing a service request out inside the TransactionScope however the service request is completely ignoring the TransactionScope. I want to be able to deterministically see what is captured by the TransactionScope not just assume stuff. Surely this is possible? The link doesn't show any information regarding that.

Comment: Its toString () method returns the string of the current object. I don't know if that works for you, but you can see what it [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=net-5.0).